# Is there a repository/library of ready-to-use postsharp aspects?

Tags: aop, postsharp

I'm about to start using PostSharp in my project. I'd like to leverage existing aspects. Is there a repository or a list of ready-to-use, user contributed, postsharp aspects? Something like the [Mercurial'S extensions list](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UsingExtensions).

For instance, is there a production ready implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern (I know there is one in the examples but I don't know if it's production ready)...

*I saw the [Shared Add Ins](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download/addins) page on postsharp's website but it's not really what I'm looking for.*

Comment: Feel free, future viewers of this question, to help yourself to any of the ones in my personal library, both my own and adopted from elsewhere:

https://github.com/cerebrate/arkane-base/tree/master/Arkane.Aspects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time, there is no aspect library that you can pull from. at least any "official". I have created my own to be used within my organization. You'll probably have to do the same.

That is a good idea, but not everyone will be able to use all aspects though. They would need to be configurable. The problem is that the business rules going into each hook will vary by organization so what's the point?

As far as the INotifyPropertyChanged aspect in the examples, that is a great place to start as it's one of the more popular aspects. I've used it several times in production. However, you should always test.

Answer (score 0):

We have a whole bunch of aspects created and after cleanup will release them on Github not too far in the future. However this does not answer your question right now. I am willing to share what we have so far. Do you have a blog or something likewise where I can contact you?